# Spring boot Failed to validate a newly established connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have deployed my Spring Boot web app in Azure cloud. Using a MySQL DB which is limited to only 4 connections. Following is the datasource properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.max-active=4
spring.datasource.connection-test-query="SELECT 1"
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
```

Since my app loses the db connection and not recovering from it I have added the test-on-borrow property. I am using JDBCTemplate.

I am getting the following exception very frequently and still the app works. I need to know whether this exception is because of the datasource properties or the limited number of connection(4). If I increase the connection will this exception go away.

**Exception Message**

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Failed to validate a newly established connection.Failed to validate a newly established connection.
```

**Failed Method**

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection
```

Comment: I replaced spring.datasource.connection-test-query with spring.datasource.validation-query and set the value as spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1. Now not getting any exceptions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is happening because of the datasource properties. By adding the test-on-borrow property, you have specified that a connection should be validated. The validation fails because the query is invalid. Drop the quotes on the query to fix it:

```
spring.datasource.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```